# FFMPEG: Need to mix dow multiple audio stream to single stereo

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an input file with 2 stereo stream of audio.
I am trying to create an output wav file with the audio mixdown: 
first stereo stream mixdown to left channel of a single stereo stream
Second stereo stream mixdown to right channel of the same stereo stream.
So output file have only one stereo stream.
I have tried different things but its not clear how to manage streams and channels inside them. Found no example on how to do this.

I've tried playing with -filter_complex , amix, and amerge filters, as well as the -map parameter, but I can't seem to find the right combination of values.

Here was my input file looks like:

```
Input #0,
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2018-03-20T16:48:32.000000Z
    com.apple.finalcutstudio.media.uuid: 2BE95371-6901-42C7-AB84-6357F53A4592
  Duration: 00:05:40.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32679 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apco / 0x6F637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 29590 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23976 tbn, 23976 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-20T16:48:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 Proxy
      timecode        : 09:59:20:00

Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-20T16:48:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler

Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-20T16:48:32.000000Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=1c|c0=0.5*c0+0.5*c1[left];[0:a:1]pan=1c|c0=0.5*c0+0.5*c1[right];[left][right]amerge[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le out.mov
```

Each stream is downmixed to mono; then merged to a stereo stream.

To output to a WAVE, drop the `-map 0:v`.

Comment: This is awsome.  Doing the right thing. I just forgot to mention i am outputing to a .wav file.  Did not like the command:   here is the output:                                                                                              
 wav @ 0x7fed18801800] WAVE files have exactly one stream
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thx very much.     I wonder where you got all the knowledge on ffmpeg ?